# how to get android Tablet PC SNID?

Tags: android

```
TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String imei_no=mngr.getDeviceId();

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

**- it will work fine for IMEI Number of android phone but i needs
   android Tablet PC SNID No.**

Answer (score 0):

Use this method it will return both fore mobile and tablet

```
public String getImeiNumber()
        {
            String imei;
            final TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null)
                imei = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); // *** use for mobiles
            else
                imei = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); // *** use for
            return imei;
        }
```

Comment: it will show android id of tablet....but i need SNID of tablet which is getting from setting-->about tablet--> device info--> SNID of my Acer A500 model no..